# Jython Date Parsing

Tags: date, jython

Is it possible to convert "2013-12-29" to "201312" using Jython?

I tried:

```
Object.strftime("%y%m") 
Date.valueOf(Object) 
datetime.datetime.strptime(Object,"%Y%m")
```

Result in `TypeError: 'java.sql.Date' object is unsubscribe.`

Thanks In Advance

Comment: Can you show us what you've tried already?

Comment: I am using Eclipse to develop scripts for an application, and I am calling the period with an application object.  The period is returned as "2013-12-29".  I have tried Object.strftime("%y%m")  and Date.valueOf(Object) and datetime.datetime.strptime(Object,"%Y%m")

Answer (score 1):

If you work with `datetime.date` objects:

```
import datetime

d = datetime.date(2013, 12, 29)
sd = d.strftime('%Y%m')
print(sd)
```

If you already have string formated as `YYYY-MM-DD` and just want it to be `YYYYMM`, then use string slicing:

```
s1 = '2013-12-29'
s2 = s1[:4] + s1[5:7]
print(s2)
```

Both work with Python and Jython.

Answer (score 1):

Michał's answer is good, but I just wanted to add that `strptime` can be used to convert the original "yyyy-mm-dd" string into a `datetime`, before converting it back to a "yyyymm" string:

```
>>> import datetime
>>> s1 = '2013-12-29'
>>> d = datetime.datetime.strptime(s1, '%Y-%m-%d')
>>> sd = d.strftime('%Y%m')
>>> sd
'201312'
```

Though for such a simple transformation Michał's slicing method is hard to beat.